# Redux-Form - How to initialize from state where the form is made up of components

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, redux-form

Yes you can initialize from state as per the [docs](http://redux-form.com/6.7.0/examples/initializefromstate/) however what do you do if the form has subcomponents. You want to reuse these components elsewhere but whats the sytax for initializing from state for those sub components?

For example you might have a Client component which as an Address component embeded in it. You want to intialize from state and the client state has the address information eg address, suburb and zip. You have included address as per:

```
      <FormSection name="Address">
        <Address />
      </FormSection>
```

In the Client form you have used the following to obtain and populate your Client fields:

```
  let ClientForm = reduxForm({
    form: CLIENT_FORM_NAME
  })(Client);

  let ClientForm2 = connect(
    (state, ownProps) => ({
      initialValues: state.editClient, // pull initial values from client reducer
      enableReinitialize: true
    }),
    { reducer } // bind client loading action creator
  )(ClientForm);
```

How do you poplulate the fields in the Address component? Do you need to pass props?

Answer (score 0):

No. As long as the client object you're passing into initialValues matches the object hierarchy created by the FormSection, your fields should populate.

A FormSection that looks like this

```
  <FormSection name="Address">
    <Address />
  </FormSection>
```

Expects your initialValues to have something like this as part of it

```
{
    address: {
        streetName: undefined,
        number: "123",
        zipCode: "9090"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. Think this might be it. Cant check it as an upgrade to Aspnet has killed my project. Have to rebuild it. Will confirm and get back.